# How to deal with github-style URL with Emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

Take this url `https://github.com/Jasig/cas/tree/master/cas-server-core/src/main/java/org` as an example, the part after `/tree`(`master/casserver-core/src/main/java/org` in this url) could contain any number of segments.

Is it possible to deal with these dynamic segments with one `Route`, or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard route described in the [Defining Your Routes Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard-globbing-routes).

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('tree', {path: '/tree/*path'});
});
```

Then you can access the path in your route like this:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var path = params.path;
    }
});
```